# Sinon stub returns empty response when mocking multiple methods of same object

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon, sinon-chai

I am trying to mock two methods in a object using sinon. One of it returns the expected response but the other method returns an empty json.

```
describe("Unit test cases ", () => {
  describe("scenario 1", function() {
    let getResponse, updateResponse;
    before(function() {
      getResponse = sinon
        .stub(DataApi.prototype, "getState")
        .returns(
          Promise.resolve(
            JSON.parse(
              fs.readFileSync("./test/get-response.json").toString("utf8")
            )
          )
        );
      updateResponse = sinon
        .stub(DataApi.prototype, "updateState")
        .returns(
          Promise.resolve(
            JSON.parse(
              fs.readFileSync("./test/update-response.json").toString("utf8")
            )
          )
        );
    });
    after(function() {
      getResponse.restore();
      updateResponse.restore();
    });
    it("TC1", () => {
      let event;
      var fn = function() {
        try {
          console.log(
            "before testing" +
              JSON.stringify(DataApi.prototype.updatePromoteState())
          ); // returns {} instead of response json
          handle(event, context, callback);
        } catch (error) {
          throw error;
        }
      };
      expect(fn).to.not.throw("Successfully Processed");
    });
  });
});
```

Source code for updatestate method

```
public updateState (authorization: string, xB3TraceId: string, xAppName?: string) : Promise<any> {
    const localVarPath = this.basePath + '{abc}';           
    let localVarQueryParameters: any = {};
    let localVarHeaderParams: any = (<any>Object).assign({}, this.defaultHeaders);
    let localVarFormParams: any = {};


    let localVarUseFormData = false;

    let localVarRequestOptions: localVarRequest.Options = {
        method: 'PUT',
        qs: localVarQueryParameters,
        headers: localVarHeaderParams,
        uri: localVarPath,
        json: true,
        body: ObjectSerializer.serialize(promoteState, "PromoteState")
    };

    return new Promise<{ response: http.IncomingMessage; body?: any;  }>((resolve, reject) => {
        localVarRequest(localVarRequestOptions, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                if (response.statusCode && response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode <= 299) {
                    resolve({ response: response, body: body });
                } else {
                    reject({ response: response, body: body });
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

}

The source code for getState is also similar to the above.

How to mock multiple methods in the same method so that it returns the expected response.

Comment: Can you please add the source code of `DataApi.prototype.updatePromoteState`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you use the stubs are correct and should work. And they are actually working, the problem is the mock methods here are returning promises (`Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(...))`).

```
      console.log(
        "before testing" +
          JSON.stringify(DataApi.prototype.updatePromoteState())
      ); // returns {} instead of response json
```

The code above tries to log the promise, not the actual value.

You can add an `await` keyword before the function call and change the fn function to async. So it becomes more or less:

```
  const fn = async () => {
    try {
      console.log(
        'before testing' + JSON.stringify(DataApi.prototype.updateState()),
      );
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  };
```

or remove `Promise.resolve`s within stub functions.